# number of degrees of freedom - afex repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, degrees-of-freedom

I am running a repeated-measures ANOVA using the `afex` package.

My subset information:
The variables are all factors, execpt the dependent variable, and I have 2 between-subject factors (Drink and Order) and 2 within-subject factors (Round and Reality):

```r
> str(Subset_2)
'data.frame':   196 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Subjects  : Factor w/ 49 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Order     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Drink     : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ Round     : Factor w/ 2 levels "round1","round2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Amplitudes: num  6.47 4.85 6.44 5.74 2.41 ...
 $ id        : Factor w/ 49 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Reality   : Factor w/ 2 levels "reality1","reality2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

When I run the anova, I would expect my degrees of freedom to be 3 and 45, since they are calculated as: df1 = k-1 and df2 = N-k, in my case k = 4, so df1 = 3 and df2 = 45, but this doesn't happen, nor I receive a print with the message of sphericity assumption ...

```r
aov_1 <- aov_car(Amplitudes ~ Reality*Drink*Round*Order + 
                 Error(id/Round*Reality), data=Subset_2)
aov1

|Effect                    |df    |MSE   |F         |ges   |p.value |
|:-------------------------|:-----|:-----|:---------|:-----|:-------|
|Drink                     |1, 45 |24.47 |0.02      |<.001 |.882    |
|Order                     |1, 45 |24.47 |0.00      |<.001 |.951    |
|Drink:Order               |1, 45 |24.47 |0.05      |.001  |.819    |
|Round                     |1, 45 |1.35  |1.80      |.002  |.186    |
|Drink:Round               |1, 45 |1.35  |0.91      |<.001 |.345    |
|Order:Round               |1, 45 |1.35  |5.79 *    |.006  |.020    |
|Drink:Order:Round         |1, 45 |1.35  |0.19      |<.001 |.663    |
|Reality                   |1, 45 |2.18  |33.12 *** |.053  |<.001   |
|Drink:Reality             |1, 45 |2.18  |1.44      |.002  |.236    |
|Order:Reality             |1, 45 |2.18  |0.00      |<.001 |.967    |
|Drink:Order:Reality       |1, 45 |2.18  |0.02      |<.001 |.881    |
|Round:Reality             |1, 45 |0.76  |5.09 *    |.003  |.029    |
|Drink:Round:Reality       |1, 45 |0.76  |0.01      |<.001 |.925    |
|Order:Round:Reality       |1, 45 |0.76  |0.05      |<.001 |.820    |
|Drink:Order:Round:Reality |1, 45 |0.76  |0.10      |<.001 |.757    |
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
```

Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: can you say explicitly what you're denoting by `k`? Each of your effects quantifies the difference/variance among two categories (e.g. `Drink=1` vs `Drink=2`), so it seems entirely natural to me that df1==1.

Comment: The df1 is calculated as number of groups (k) minus 1, the number of groups in my case is 4, right?